# Creating library in iOS with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, ios7

I have an iOS app named A which has `A.sqlite` file in it. I am trying to create a library named A, so that it can be used as library in other projects. How to include `A.sqlite` file inside new iOS app named B. I want to store some information inside A.sqlite by including it in app B. I went through below links, but I didn't get how to create a library with Core Data and include it in other applications.

[LINK 1](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)
[LINK 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7lxkv-sZA0)

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQLite but the same should be applicable for coredata as well. You need to add the coredata to app A which is a library and provide API's to access coredata through app A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should i create separate NSManagedObjectcontext for library A and app B?

Comment: In library A the API's exposed should be able to do CRUD operations. As i am not much aware of coredata i will not be able to say in detail.